# find key with a value among multiple value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to find a key with a certain value in a certain position in a dictionary. My dictionary looks like this.

```
>dict
>{'1': ['4166908', '4166673'],
 '2': ['4166835', '4167465', '4169369'],
 '3': ['4169108', '4169208', '4170285'],
 '4': ['4170065']}
```

Here's an example of what I am trying to do.

Return key that has value '4169208' in position 1 and value '4170285'.
The returned key should be '3'. Like this,

m='4169208'
n='4170285'

```
for key, value in mydict.iteritems():
    if value[1] == m and value[2] == n:
        print key
```

It would be great if I can do this using 'itervalues()' or a similar function.

Comment: What do you mean by position 1? Also, could you please show the code you have written up to attempt to do this please? And explain what is currently not working out for you.

Comment: Updated question to explain my quandary better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on strictly correcting your code, the only modification you need to do is to first check to make sure the list you are checking has a length `>=` 2. Then you can check for the condition of looking at position 1 and 2.

```
d = {'1': ['4166908', '4166673'],
 '2': ['4166835', '4167465', '4169369'],
 '3': ['4169108', '4169208', '4170285'],
 '4': ['4170065']}


for i, v in d.iteritems():
    if len(v) >= 2 and v[1] == '4169208' and v[2] == '4170285':
        print(i)
```

Comment: Thank you, turns out my issue was sillier than I had assumed.

Answer (score 0):

python3.5

```
mydict = {'1': ['4166908', '4166673'],
...  '2': ['4166835', '4167465', '4169369'],
...  '3': ['4169108', '4169208', '4170285'],
...  '4': ['4170065']}
>>> mydict
{'1': ['4166908', '4166673'], '4': ['4170065'], '2': ['4166835', '4167465', '4169369'], '3': ['4169108', '4169208', '4170285']}
>>> for key, value in mydict.items():
...     if all(v in value for v in [ '4169208', '4170285']):
...         print(key)
...
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary = {'1': ['4166908', '4166673'],
     '2': ['4166835', '4167465', '4169369'],
     '3': ['4169108', '4169208', '4170285'],
     '4': ['4170065']}

def get_key_by_value(dictionary, check_values_list):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if all(item in value for item in check_values_list):
            yield key

print list(get_key_by_value(dictionary, ['4169208', '4170285']))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'1': ['4166908', '4166673'], '2': ['4166835', '4167465', '4169369'],
     '3': ['4169108', '4169208', '4170285'], '4': ['4170065']}

for i, v in d.items():
    if '4169208' in v or '4170285' in v:
        print i
```